# T-SQL - Error converting data type - show offending row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

On a simple `INSERT` command, I am getting an error:

> Error converting data type...

The source data has multiple sources and combined makes hundreds of thousands of rows.

Can I re-write my statement to catch the error and show the offending data?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Requests for code:

```
insert Table_A 
  ([ID]
  ,[rowVersion]
  ,[PluginId]
  ,[rawdataId]
    ...
    ...
    ...
    )
select [ID]
      ,[rowVersion]
      ,[PluginId]
      ,[rawdataId]
       ...
       ...
       ...
FROM TABLE_B
```

Comment: It would help if we could see your query... and maybe some data.

Comment: And... where is the query?

Comment: @Warren Show us your code

Comment: There's no general provision in SQL Server to find the offending data - if you want it, you need to write an equivalent `SELECT` query with a `WHERE` clause that tries to find the data that can't be converted. The "reason" is that there could be multiple pieces of offending data, and actually computing all of the offences could be expensive - an expense that the `INSERT` shouldn't necessarily incur since it's going to fail anyway.

Comment: What is the data types of the columns in `Table_A` and the corresponding data types for the columns in `Table_B`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two approaches that I've taken, when dealing with this problem.  The issue is caused by an implicit conversion from a string to a date.

If you happen to know which field is being converted (which may be true in your example, but not always in mine), then just do:

```
select *
from table_B
where isdate(col) = 0 and col is not null
```

This may not be perfect for all data types, but it has worked well for me in practice.

Sometimes, when I want to find the offending row in a *select* statement, I would run the `select`, outputting the data into text rather than a grid.  This is one of the options in SSMS, along the row of icons beneath the menus.  It will output all the rows before the error, which sort of lets you identify the row with the error.  This works best when there is an `order by` clause, but for debugging purpose it has worked for me.

In your case, I might create a temporary table that holds strings, and then do the analysis on this temporary table, particularly if Table_B is not really a table but a more complicated query.

Answer (score 1):

The query statement `insert into...select` or  `select ... into ... from`  has no capability to find the offending data. Instead you can use **BCP** to set the `max_erros` and `err_files` to output all the offending data into an error file. Then you can simply analyze the error file to find all offending rows. 
 **[MSDN BCP]**[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to do a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to find the problematic value(s). You can do that both by column and by row:

- Try to insert only half the columns, if that works the other half of the columns.
- Try to insert only half the number of rows. If that works the other half.

And repeat until you found the problem.